# Logged In cookie gets saved but not Auth cookie

Tags: cookies, authentication

I am trying to get WordPress to run on *PHP-CGI* which I call from my *ExpressJS* *(Node JS)* server. After getting some bugs worked out on my end, I finally got the front-end working. I can login and the admin bar shows up, but when I try to access any of the admin pages, I get redirected to the login page. This applies to all admin pages including `/wp-admin/user/profile.php`.

I've pretty much ruled out anything in the *NodeJS* setup -- it is definitely communicating and even setting the `logged_in` cookie -- but it could still be corrupting something on the return trip. In the request there are two `logged_in` cookies set, but when it gets to my theme's `functions.php` file, `$_COOKIE` only has one `logged_in` cookie and a test cookie, no auth cookie.

So, how do I check which cookies WP is sending so I can see if that is what is getting to my browser. And besides that, what else might be the problem.

I can't get into the admin area, so everything is still default.

Running WP 4.4.1 and PHP 5.6.12. No `.htaccess` or *Apache* directives, but I have complete control over everything going into *PHP-CGI*.

**Update**: Here is the `Set-Cookie` header being sent in the response to the login post request:

```
'Set-Cookie': ' wordpress_logged_in_c8a8dd254728998d538ca196677bea9c=Admin%7C1452550201%7CycLtSl7NAXlefnelrxvq9SxBjE8YLKBO8Bkg2yVY9gu%7Cb8d3bd326e5e47c3b22b7518d989f44786f2b89e42434a0585d7b507d0671bda; path=/wp-master/; httponly',
```

**To anyone trying to break in:** This is running on my local computer, not online.

Comment: Is it possible that this depends on the browser?

Comment: Well, I don't know, but other WordPress sites work perfectly fine on the same browser.